# How to iterate through a html table inputs using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to iterator through a table containing input fields without using tab.

As tab only iterate through right.

I need to use keyboard arrow to iterate through the input fields.

```
<td class="td-pad" *ngFor="let size of sizeRange;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="" class="form-control fs-tr" (change)="changeSelectedQuantity('F',size)" [(ngModel)]="selectedStock[stock]['F'][size]" [disabled]="availableStock[stock]['F'][size]<=0" >
        <div class="input-group-append">
                <span class="input-group-text">/ {{availableStock[stock]['F'][size] ? availableStock[stock]['F'][size] : 0}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Post the code that you have so far.

Comment: `As tab only iterate through right.` means what? Shift-tab goes the other way

Comment: My code only have tables and input tags. I am able to traverse using tabs. but cannot do it with arrow keys

Comment: @mplungjan yeah that I got to know.. But arrow doesn't work...

Comment: Added html snippet

Comment: Using arrow keys to select inputs is a bad idea.  What is the user meant to do if they want to move the cursor *inside* the input?  Changing default behaviour is pretty much always a bad idea.

Comment: @Archer ok.. but this is my project expectation

Comment: @JeetheshKotian That does not change the fact that what you're asking to do is as close to "wrong" as you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a below code which we have used in one of our application for the same requirement

Using recursion I iterate through the DOM to check if the element is "tr" or "td" and then find the next or previous sibling depending on the key press. Then get the child input to set the focus.

Hope this helps

```js
const NEXT = "next",
  PREV = "prev",
  UP = "up",
  DOWN = "down",
  TR = "tr",
  TD = "td";

function arrowPressed(element, type, nName) {
  var newElement = getInput(element, type, nName);
  if (newElement != undefined && newElement != null) {
    if (newElement.disabled) {
      arrowPressed(newElement, type, nName)
    } else {
      newElement.focus();
    }
  }
}

function getInput(element, type, nName) {
  if (element != null && element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == nName) {
    if (element.nextElementSibling != null && (type == NEXT || type == DOWN)) {
      return element.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.kd-input');
    } else if (element.nextElementSibling == null && type == NEXT) {
      return getInput(element.parentElement, DOWN, TR);
    } else if (element.previousElementSibling != null && (type == PREV || type == UP)) {
      return element.previousElementSibling.querySelector('.kd-input');
    } else if (element.previousElementSibling == null && type == PREV) {
      return getInput(element.parentElement, UP, TR);
    }
  } else {
    return getInput(element.parentElement, type, nName);
  }
  return null;
}

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  if (evt.target && evt.target.className == 'kd-input') {
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
      case 37:
        arrowPressed(evt.target, PREV, TD);
        break;
      case 39:
        arrowPressed(evt.target, NEXT, TD);
        break;
      case 38:
        arrowPressed(evt.target, UP, TR);
        break;
      case 40:
        arrowPressed(evt.target, DOWN, TR);
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Input1</th>
    <th>Input2</th>
    <th>Input3</th>
    <th>Input4</th>
    <th>Input5</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input" disabled></td>
    <td><input class="kd-input"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ohhk.. let me check this out.. Thanks